# Adding pod 'Firebase/AppIndexing' and pod 'FirebaseInAppMessaging' together

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-remote-config, firebase-in-app-messaging

Unable to have both together due to varying version dependency

`[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseAnalytics":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    FirebaseAnalytics (= 3.9.0, ~> 3.7, ~> 3.8, ~> 3.9)

In Podfile:
    Firebase/Core was resolved to 3.17.0, which depends on
      FirebaseAnalytics (= 3.9.0)

```
Firebase/RemoteConfig was resolved to 3.17.0, which depends on
  FirebaseRemoteConfig (= 1.3.4) was resolved to 1.3.4, which depends on
    FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.7)

FirebaseInAppMessaging was resolved to 0.11.0, which depends on
  FirebaseAnalytics (~> 5.1)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `pod update`. FirebaseInAppMessaging was introduced in Firebase 5.x and incompatible with Firebase 3.x. `Firebase/RemoteConfig` needs to also be updated to 5.x to be compatible.

`Firebase/AppIndexing` was deprecated in Firebase 3.x and should be removed in order to use more recent Firebase versions.

Comment: @phoenixroy If the answer was useful, you can upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: Why Firebase/AppIndexing is deprecated and what should we use in its replacement?

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry See https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/ios/app

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Yes I have already read it, it's just deep linking with Universal links which we usually do in IOS. But then what is the role of Firebase Indexing? How to implement that?